# Firestore 'FieldValue.increment(value)' firing intermittently

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a class whose sole purpose is to record a transaction in a Firestore instance. As part of the process, I check several places if a particular doc already exists in a given collection. If it doesn't exit, I create the doc and set the name and amount. If it already exists, I update the document by calling FieldValue.increment(amount).

However, this doesn't always work. I haven't found a pattern, but since the whole concept is to track costs, I'm leery of using this functionality if I can't trust it. I've included the class definition and one of the code sections that checks for the existing doc and either sets or updates the data.

What am I missing here?

[EDIT]

I've updated the code per the suggestions below, and I've updated the code listing below to reflect the changes.

```
class Ledger {
  static Future<void> createEntry(
    String date,
    double amount,
    String payee,
    String job,
    String costcode,
    String? note,
  ) async {
    final String? uuid = Auth().currentUser?.uid;
    final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('$uuid');
    final transactionsRef = userRef.collection('transactions');
    final payeeRef = userRef.collection('payees').doc(payee);
    final jobRef = userRef.collection('jobs').doc(job);
    final costcodeRef = userRef.collection('costcodes').doc(costcode);

    ///?  WRITE TRANSACTION TO USER/TRANSACTIONS COLLECTION
    final transactionData = {
      'date': date,
      'amount': amount,
      'payee': payee,
      'job': job,
      'costcode': costcode,
      'note': note,
    };
    transactionsRef.add(transactionData);

    ///? WRITE PAYEE/AMOUNT TO USER/PAYEES COLLECTION
    final payeeData = {'name': payee, 'amount': FieldValue.increment(amount)};
    await payeeRef
        .set({payeeData, SetOptions(merge: true)} as Map<String, dynamic>);

{...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need an `if-then-else` for this, calling increment on a non-existing value increments it from 0. Did you consider [using `set` with `mergeOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) (second code sample) and always setting the job name and the increment?

If job names are important and should be unique, you can also consider using the job name as the document ID.

---

I think what you want is this:

```
final DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .doc("$user")
    .collection("jobs")
    .doc(job);
await documentReference.set({
  'name': job,
  'amount': FieldValue.increment(amount), // 
}, SetOptions(merge: true)); //
```

---

From the [repro](https://zapp.run/edit/firestore-set-with-merge-z73406107350?file=lib/main.dart) I created:

```
final data = {'name': "hello", 'amount': FieldValue.increment(42)};
await doc.set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Comment: The job name is the document name (.doc(job);). 'Job' is the String passed in from the calling code to the constructor. What I *think* I'm doing is getting a reference to users/user/jobs/[JOB NAME] and then checking if it exists or not. If it exists, all I want to do is update the 'amount' value by incrementing it with the value passed to the constructor. If it doesn't exist, I want to create it with doc ID [JOB NAME] and then set the 'amount' key to the value of 'amount' passed in to the constructor.

Comment: "The job name is the document name" Oh right, I missed that. In that case you definitely don't need two cases. Just use `set` with `merge: true` as shown in the second code sample on the link I shared, so without every trying to read the document. If that `set` call creates the document, it increments from 0. Also see the code sample I added to my answer, which replaces everything after the `WRITE JOB/AMOUNT TO USER/JOBS COLLECTION` comment in your code. --- If you can't get that to work, edit your to show what you with `set` and `merge` and what result you got, so we can check.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Your way makes the code more compact and more readable - only problem is it isn't working for me. I get an error at { merge: true } that says "The argument type 'Map<dynamic, bool>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SetOptions?'" Looking at the docs, it seems maybe this feature has been updated - but they don't show usage examples, and I can't figure out how to pass the merge option to 'set' correctly.

Comment: After some Googling, I've updated the code (see revised code listing above) to cast the .set operation to a Map. This shows no errors in the editor, but upon running I get the following error: "_CastError (type '_Set<Object>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)." Still not sure where the problem is.

Comment: You're trying to put the `SetOptions` into the data, which is not correct. See line 29-30 here for the working code: https://zapp.run/edit/firestore-set-with-merge-z73406107350?file=lib/main.dart: `payeeRef.set(payeeData, SetOptions(merge: true));`

Comment: That did the trick - thanks! If you'll edit your code snippet above to match what's in the link, I'll mark it as the correct answer. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I had already fixed the code in my answer to pass the `SetOptions` correctly. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The code snippet above doesn't work, and doesn't match the code that does work in the link you posted a few comments above. I've marked it as the answer anyway in case maybe I mis-typed it. Thanks again for the help.